# How to add Image on UIButton on right side and contentMode don't working with image?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When i added image (by storyboard) to a button image content Mode not working .When i fix it(iPhone) by image insets and title insets on another device (iPad) its lose expect ratio ? how can i fix it ??

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of how it looks like?

Comment: If nothing works, create a image with clear background and your image (Your image in right/left side) and set it as a background image of UIButton

Comment: Do you mean `image content Mode` by button's image-view's content mode or UIButton's semantic property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and modify EdgeInset as you want, and assign your outlet as `DropdownButton` instead of `IUButton`

```
class DropdownButton: UIButton {

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignment.left

    if self.imageView?.image != nil {
        // Move icon to right side
        self.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(
            top: 0,
            left: self.bounds.size.width - self.imageView!.image!.size.width - 10,
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0)
        // Move title to left side
        self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, -self.imageView!.frame.size.width + 10, 5, 5)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Semantic` to `Force Right-To-Left` of UIButton to set image at right side. Default `Semantic` value `Unspecified`.

The property "Semantic" in the storyboard is a rule which allows the iOS to know if the view should be flipped or not. - [Apple's Documentations](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set it programmatically. For example if the device is iPad or iPhone set the insets programatically. For example `button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)`. try this code in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`. I am using 0 just for the sake of understanding, use your own measured values.